# How to make Tax Category field in AP Invoice line required and still update detail total and balance

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to make a field required on the line item of an AP Invoice, the Tax Category field. However when I change the field to be required I run into the problem of the detail total and the balance to no longer update on the form.

What I've tried doing is eliminating the PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing of the PXDefault attribute of the TaxCategoryID. This causes the field to be required on the form, however as I've stated, it also causes the form to no longer update totals. I've tried changing the PersistingCheck to PXPersistingCheck.Null, but this also prevents the totals from being updated.

Originally the PXDefault attribute for the Tax Category field is as follows:

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.taxCategoryID, 
      Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<APTran.inventoryID>>>>), 
      PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

This is what my code is:

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.taxCategoryID,
     Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<APTran.inventoryID>>>>))]
```

What I want is to be able to have the Tax Category field required and the totals to be updated as usual, but I am not able to due to something in the code preventing the totals to be updated when the PXDefault attribute of the Tax Category field is changed.

Is there anything additional I must do in order for these issues to be resolved or am possibly going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly change the `PersistenceCheck` and add `Required=true` to `PXUIFieldAttribute` for showing a red asterisk symbol near the column's name. Please see the example of how to do that using `PXMergeAttributesAttribute` and `PXCustomizeBaseAttribute`:

```
public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    #region Event Handlers
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXUIFieldAttribute), nameof(PXUIFieldAttribute.Required),true)]
    [PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXDefaultAttribute), nameof(PXDefaultAttribute.PersistingCheck), null)]
    protected virtual void APTran_TaxCategoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }
    #endregion
}
```